# How do formulas for (affine) projections imply each other?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to learn and understand projections so that I can work more on this field. I will try to make my question simple. I understand that the projection onto a hyperplane $$H=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\langle a,x\rangle=b\}$$ has a closed form which is

$$\tag{1} P_{H}(x)=a-\frac{\langle a,x\rangle -b}{||a||^2}a $$
The projection onto the subspace $$S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\langle a,x\rangle=0\}$$
is defined by $$\tag{2} P_{S}(x)=a-\frac{\langle a,x\rangle}{||a||^2}a$$
The projection onto a subspace $S$ can also be defined by 
$$\tag{3} P_{S}(x)=A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}(x)$$ where $A$ is the matrix whose columns are linearly independent and are a spaning set of $S.$

I understand that an affine subspace (hyperplane as a special case) is a translation of a subspace, that is
$$H=S+a$$ for some vector $a\in H$, and also we have a translation formula
$$P_{H=S+a}(x)=P_{S}(x-a)+a.$$ I can understand how every one of these formulas is been derived but I can not find a good argument of how to find one to another (how to go from one to another), that is how we get (1) from (3) or (3) from (1), and (2) from (3) and vice versa. I really want to learn this and hope that someone can explain it to me.

I appreciate your help. Thanks.